# Move two matches so that no triangle remains

Tags: matches

This puzzle comes from Nobuyuki Yoshigahara.  Move two matches so that no triangle remains.  There are at least five different solutions.  How many solutions can you find?

You can’t burn the matches.  The number of matches in the solution must equal the number of matches in the original picture.

[image: Three equilateral triangles made with matches in a horizontal row (with the middle triangle slightly raised)]

Comment: @DialFrost It’s not a math thing.  It’s a word thing, literally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137279/discussion-between-dialfrost-and-will-octagon-gibson).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I estimate there are 6 solutions, 5 of mine and 1 of @loopy_walt's

> N O TRIANGLE

> ```
>     o o        o o        o o           .
>    /   \      /   \      /   \          .
>   /     \     o   o     /     \         .
>  /       \     \ /      o------         .
>
>  Ignore the dots (formatting purposes)
> ```

Taking an idea from @loopy_walt's solution, I conclude the following:

> +1-1=0

> ```
>    o        o            o     .
>    |       / \          / \    .
> ------o   /   \ -----o /   \   .
>    |     /     \      /     \  .
>    |    o-------o    o-------o .
>
>  Ignore the dots (they are for formatting purposes)
> ```

and

> 1-1=0

> ```
>      o            o               .
>     / \          / \    -----o    .
>    /   \ -----o /   \   -----o    .
>   /     \      /     \            .
>  o-------o    o-------o           .
>
>  Ignore the dots (they are for formatting purposes)
> ```

and

> -1+1=0

> ```
>             o      o      o     .
>            / \     |     / \    .
> ------o   /   \ ------o /   \   .
>          /     \   |   /     \  .
>         o-------o  |  o-------o .
>
>  Ignore the dots (they are for formatting purposes)
> ```

and

> 1-1=0

> ```
>     o       o             o      o     .
>     |      / \            |     / \    .
>     |     /   \  ------o  |    /   \   .
>     |    /     \          |   /     \  .
>     |   o-------o         |  o-------o .
>
>  Ignore the dots (they are for formatting purposes)
> ```

Comment: Great job!  Your first solution is new to me.

Answer (score 6):

We can form the

> absolute difference of two identical Deltas which is zero

like so

> ```
>     o     o               o      |
>     |    / \             / \     |
>     |   /   \  -------o /   \    |
>     |  /     \         /     \   |
>     | o-------o       o-------o  o
> ```

Comment: That’s cool!  Now I know that there are at least three solutions to this puzzle.

Comment: Wow! Imaginative solution! +1

Answer (score 0):

> Does a triangle only count if it has no matches crossing its interior?

If so, then here's one method:

> Take one match each from two of the triangles. Break one in half. Place them so that they form a Y on top of the third triangle, with each broken half crossing one side, and the unbroken match crossing the third side.

Comment: I want to say that doesn’t count because the third triangle is still there it’s just partially hidden.  Try again.